# Object Declaration inside classes

Tags: java, object, declaration, new-operator

```
class Node
{
  Node next;
  int data;
}
```

As in this above example for creating a node in a link list, why did we not use "new" keyword to declare the node object inside the node class?

Comment: Up voted. I think the question is clear. I wonder why it was down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` is not used for declaration but for creating an object.

The code

```
 Node next;
```

is a declaration only.

To create a `Node` object you will need to use one of `Node`'s constructors and do something like:

```
 next = new Node(.....);
```

Comment: @P_K Thanks for accepting. Other answers are also helpful, consider up voting helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

The node object hasn't been created, it is still null.

```
Node next = new Node(...)
```

The above creates the Node.

Comment: Up voted. It is correct as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use new to *create* objects, not for declaring them. `next` is null before you assign it an object.